# Installing Express 2013 for Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xamarin

Good day, I'am trying to install express 2013 with update 2 for Windows in order to run Xamarin.Forms ... The error I'm currently receiving are "This version of Visual Studio requires a computer **with a newer version of Windows**". My operating system are currently running Windows 7 professional.. Is it required to have Windows 8 to install Express 2013 with Update 2?

EDIT: I've was able to install microsoft visual express 2013 for desktop at http://www.microsoft.com/en-my/download/details.aspx?id=40787

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As illustrated in the download link,

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42670

Windows 8 is required if you want to install this update. This is expected, as this update primarily targets Windows Store and Windows Phone apps.

To play with Xamarin.Forms, you can solely use Xamarin Studio. Note that to use Xamarin.Forms in Visual Studio, you usually need Visual Studio Professional editions. Express editions do not allow any third party add-ons to be installed, so you won't get Xamarin bits there.

Answer (score 0):

no not required to upgrade to windows 8....check the recruitment for visual studio and installation details at Microsoft.com